# Chrome Title Bar Color

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, colors, themes

Sorry if this isn't the right place for this question. I saw a similar question located [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1125971/google-chrome-changed-title-bar-color-does-not-inherit-correct-color-from-wind) so it seemed like it might be appropriate.

A few days ago I mis-clicked something in the Chrome title bar. It changed the title bar color from light gray (#f5f5f5) to darker gray (#cccccc). I know it seems really petty, but it's actually quite annoying when you've been used to a certain color for so long.

Here's what it used to look like:

[image]

And here's what it looks like now:

[image]

I realize it's just a slightly darker color, but when the window goes in and out of focus, really noticable. I've also talked to a few other people and their color is still the light gray version (picture 1).

Does anyone know of something I might've done to make this happen? I've tried going into my windows settings (windows 10) and changing the theme, as well as using a chrome theme, but nothing seems to reset it to the "default". I also tried installing a theme then pressing the "Reset to default" button in the chrome themes, but it's still dark gray.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try visiting chrome://flags/#windows10-custom-titlebar, and change "Custom-drawn Windows 10 Titlebar" to Disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a change brought on by Chrome 67 which was recently promoted to stable. I hadn't updated to 67 and saw the old color, updated, and it was the new color.